# JavaScript for loop inside async function

Tags: javascript, promise

I am running into promise error inside for loop which is inside async function.

```
var circles=[];
async function displayMarkersOnGoogleMap(locations) {
    try {

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlong,
                title: ""
                icon: {
                    url: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png", 
                    labelOrigin: { x: 12, y: -10 }
                },
                map: map,
                label: {
                    text: "",
                    color: "red",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontsize:"16px"
                }
            });
            

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {

                console.warn("Business Marker clicked");
                var distanceInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
                    currentPosMarker.getPosition(),
                    marker.getPosition()
            );

                    try {

                        circles.forEach(async (circle) => {
                            await circle.setMap(null);
                        })
                                              
                    } catch (e) {

                    }
                   

                    if (i == undefined)
                        i = 0;

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        var circle = drawCircle(map, latlong, locations[i].rangeLimitInMeters);
                        circles.push(circle);
                    }, 5000);

                   
                var content = "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" + locations[i].locationName + "</span>"
                content = content + "<br/> " + locations[i].address + "<br/> " + locations[i].city + ", " + locations[i].state;
                if (locations[i].locationOpenStatus == "CLOSE") {
                    content = content + "<br/><span class='badge badge-danger'>" + locations[i].locationOpenStatus + "</span>";
                }
                else {
                    content = content + "<br/><span class='badge badge-success'>" + locations[i].locationOpenStatus + "</span>";
                }
                content = content + "<br/><span style='font-weight: bold;'> Time : </span> " + locations[i].locationStartTime + " To " + locations[i].locationStopTime;
                             
         
                  
                    infowindow.marker = marker;
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            markersArrray.push(marker);
        }

    
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Javascript:displayMarkersOnGoogleMap:-" + e.errorMessage );
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I get around this ?
All I am trying to do is clear all the previous Circles that I might have drawn , before drawing the new one.

Comment: What does the error you're getting say? The screenshot just shows the promise object. Also, since the event handler is synchronous, the async process will happen at an unpredictable time with relation to the rest of the handler.

Comment: What does the `drawCircle` function return?

Comment: `displayMarkersOnGoogleMap` should not be `async`, it just creates markers and installs the event listeners, but doesn't wait for anything.

Comment: Is `circle.setMap` even an asynchronous function? What does it do? What is a `circle`?

Comment: why don't you simply use `for await...of`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: displayMarkersOnGoogleMap is async because it is invoked  from Blazor( an UI like angular)

Comment: @MattU, the problem was indeed in the drawCircle , it was returning null

Answer (score 2):

```
circles.forEach(async (circle) => {
  await circle.setMap(null);
})
```

This right here, wont work as you expect it to. forEach loop doesn't work with async callbacks. Even if you explicitly mark your callback function as async, forEach loop wont wait for it to complete the promise.

Instead try with a for...of loop.This would execute whatever is inside synchronously, in the order you normally read the code.

```
for(const circle of circles) {
  await circle.setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Yup. Or, if you want things to happen concurrently, `await Promise.all(circles.map(...))`